# Django model set field default to another field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've spent some time reading through other questions but I feel like my problem is different, so here it is:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
        foo = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
        bar = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, default=foo)
```

I would like `bar` to take `foo` as a default value but I get a

```
TypeError: conversion from DecimalField to Decimal is not supported
```

What should I do? Should I use the override function, as suggested in other posts?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: bar is the class attribute, not a value. Before saving object you can set bar value the same as foo

Comment: Sounds so obvious.. Thanks

Comment: sorry i meant foo is the class attribute, mistype